# Cannot figure out why SUM function doesn't return the correct reuslts

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table in Snowflake:

| ASSOC_ID | ACID | ISSUE_DATE | HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE | HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE | UNSAT_PORTION | STATUS | HARMED_BILL_SAT_DATE | TRAN_ID | FLOW_AMT | REF_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-09-18 | M1 | 77.43 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-09-18 | M1 | 178.04 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM101 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M2 | 152.93 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM101 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M2 | 74.16 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM102 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M3 | 164.11 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM102 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M3 | 79.57 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM103 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M4 | 46.88 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM103 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M4 | 15.20 | quo0 |

I want to remove the FLOW_AMT column and replace it with the total FLOW_AMT for each ACID, ISSUE_DATE, and HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE. Basically, I would like to see something like this:

| ASSOC_ID | ACID | ISSUE_DATE | HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE | HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE | UNSAT_PORTION | STATUS | HARMED_BILL_SAT_DATE | TRAN_ID | FLOW_AMT | REF_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-09-18 | M1 | 255.47 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM101 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M2 | 227.09 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM102 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M3 | 243.68 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM103 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M4 | 62.08 | quo0 |

How can I achieve this? I tried

```
SUM(FLOW_AMT) over(partition by ASSOC_ID, ACID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID)
```

but it returns 665.80 for SM100. Where does that number even come from?

I was expecting the following:

| ASSOC_ID | ACID | ISSUE_DATE | HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE | HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE | UNSAT_PORTION | STATUS | HARMED_BILL_SAT_DATE | TRAN_ID | FLOW_AMT | REF_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-09-18 | M1 | 255.47 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM101 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M2 | 227.09 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM102 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M3 | 243.68 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM103 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | R | NULL | M4 | 62.08 | quo0 |

I tried this window function:

```
SUM(FLOW_AMT) over(partition by ASSOC_ID, ACID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID)
```

Comment: Please show us your complete query. Also, what database are you using?

Comment: what you expect to see is an aggregation (SUM()...GROUIP BY) by ASSOC_ID, ACID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID), not windowing. Stop looking into the WINDOW functions, and just use sum...group by

Comment: What if the first two rows had a different `HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE` or a different `UNSAT_PORTION`?

Comment: What you say you want conflicts with your query. You say you want "*total FLOW_AMT for each ACID, ISSUE_DATE, and HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE*" but your queries are `over(partition by ASSOC_ID, ACID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID)`

Comment: The unusual 665 would suggest there are some joins going on that you didn't share.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information to say what's wrong with your query. You could use a `sum` with a `group by ASSOC_ID, ACID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID` (your question is contradictory about what you want to group by, so I'm going with this). However, you can't get the results you're asking for. Not meaningfully.

Consider if your data looked like this.

| ASSOC_ID | ACID | ISSUE_DATE | HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE | HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE | UNSAT_PORTION | STATUS | HARMED_BILL_SAT_DATE | TRAN_ID | FLOW_AMT | REF_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-09-18 | M2 | 77.43 | quid |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-05 | 2020-06-28 | 9.87 | Q | 2020-09-18 | M1 | 178.04 | quo0 |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | 2020-06-06 | 2020-06-28 | 6.63 | R | 2020-10-18 | M1 | 123.45 | quo0 |

These are all in the same group, but their ungrouped columns are different. You can only have one row for the group. Which values should be used for that row? It's ambiguous.

| ASSOC_ID | ACID | ISSUE_DATE | HARMED_BILL_GEN_DATE | HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE | UNSAT_PORTION | STATUS | HARMED_BILL_SAT_DATE | TRAN_ID | FLOW_AMT | REF_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | SM100 | 2020-08-28 | ? | 2020-06-28 | ? | ? | ? | ? | 378.92 | ? |

You need to specify how to aggregate the ungrouped columns (for example, you could concatenate the different values) or remove the ungrouped columns from your result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group and reduce the rows then don't use sum with window function.
Instead use sum and groupby.

Try:

```
select SUM(FLOW_AMT)  as FLOW_AMT_SUM, ACID, ASSOC_ID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID
from table
group by  ACID, ASSOC_ID, HARMED_BILL_DUE_DATE, TRAN_ID
```